# Find start and end position of a match in a string

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have been trying to find a simple solution for the following problem in lua:
Given a string such as `str`, get the start and end position of the last occurring A-mer (one or multiple instances of `A`). E.g. for the string  `str = "123A56AA9"` the solution is `start=7`, `finish=8`.

To get the end position I can use:

`` _,finish = str:find(".*A")` -- returns 8 ``

but I cannot find any solution to get the start position. Is this possible? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`string.find` *returns* the start and end positions of the match. So the start index is that `_` variable you ignored.

Your problem is that your pattern doesn't actually match what you're looking for. If you want the last sequence of "A" characters, you need to do something else. Like this:

```
local start, final = 1, 1

while(final)
  local temp_start, temp_final = str:find("A+", end)
  if(temp_start) then
    start, final = temp_start, temp_final
  else
    final = nil
  end
end
```

A cleverer, pattern-based method would be this:

```
local start, final, match = str:find("(A+)[^A]*$")
if(start) then
  final = start + (#match - 1)
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this too, `_` stores the first character in this case and is `1` in that example.

Comment: @user6465354: That's because that's what your match says. You matched an arbitrarily long sequence of characters, terminated by an "A".

Comment: @user6465354: See my updates for a fixed pattern match.

Comment: Curious about #match, why would you prefer `final = start + (#match - 1)`  over `_,final, _ = str:find("(A+)[^A]*$")`

Comment: @wsha: Because `find` always returns the area of the *pattern*, not of any of the captures within that pattern. So the found range will include any trailing `[^A]`s.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve the problem. I like to work with gmatch.
Btw. You've used `end` as variable name. But this is a reserved keyword.

```
str = "123A56AA9"
for startpos, match, endpos in str:gmatch('()(A+)()[^A]*$') do
    print(startpos, match, endpos-1)
end
```